# Cookie with a non-existant path

Tags: javascript, cookies

I am trying to create a cookie. My webpage has url `something.com/webpage`.

From JS on that page I am trying to set a cookie with path `/webpage/something_else` or `/other_page` but in both cases the cookie doesn't get set (running `document.cookie` shows `""`).

I feel like this has to be a very simple question, but cannot find any documentation on what are the restrictions on paths and why I am not allowed to create a cookie with such paths.

Command I am trying to run are pretty simple `document.cookie = "a=b; path=/webpage/abc"`

It feels like one of the most basic questions ever, what am I missing here?

EDIT

The logic behind this is that I want to send a cookie on an AJAX request to the:
`something.com/webpage/abc` which is different to what I am on now.

Comment: Does your server has header response httponly and secure set in cookies? Javascript cant manipulate it if those key word exist in the response header

Comment: Cookies aren't set using http. I set them manually executing js code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The path from where the cookie will be readable. E.g., "/", "/mydir";
>   if not specified, defaults to the current path of the current document
>   location (string or null). The path must be absolute (see RFC 2965).
>   For more information on how to use relative paths in this argument,
>   see this paragraph.

Based on your title you are setting the cookie path with non-existing path. Path suggest where the cookie will be readable/active. So i can't imagine how you will be able to see the cookie since you can't navigate to non-existing path/page. That is why it is always empty.

[See document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie/Simple_document.cookie_framework#Using_relative_URLs_in_the_path_parameter)

> Also, You can't set cookies by the look of things if its not running
>   in a web server.
>
> file:///C:/Users/me/Desktop/demo/demo.html
>
> however:
>
> http://localhost/demo/demo.html works.

As per [menztrual](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1258398/menztrual)

Comment: First thing, I am running a server :) So I can set cookies without specifying a path

Comment: Second, the path is different to the webpage I am on (though the domain matches), but I want the cookie to get sent in an ajax request to the path of the cookie

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you are checking the cookie correctly? Read http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp on how to get and check the cookie